# Hit me softly - What is the opposite of softly?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, antonyms

[These words](http://www.opposite-word.com/s/softly) won't be appropriate.

> Hit me _______.

What should I write as opposite of softly here?

Comment: "Hard" is the opposite of the "very little force" sense of "soft".

Comment: You may want to look at antonyms of gently instead of softly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Hit me ***hard***

seems to be the best option. It's opposite to 'softly' or 'gentle tap'.

---

Jasper gives us a very good point. 'hard' is different from 'hardly' so one should not get confused that opposite to 'softly' is 'hardly'. 'Hardly' means barely.

Comment: In this context, "hard" is correct.  In this context, "hardly" is incorrect -- "Hardly hit me" would mean "Barely hit me at all".

Comment: ah, that's a good point! @Jasper

Answer (score 5):

While "hit me hard" is perfectly acceptable, if you wish to emphasize that this is a challenge, you might try "**Hit me with your best shot.**"

Comment: But will 'softly', in this case, mean 'halfheartedly', or 'leniently'? It doesn't fit.

Comment: There's a song called... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try "forcefully" implying with a great deal of energy or perhaps "powerfully"?